# How to dig deep into mmcblk0?

Tags: file-system, linux, mount, android-10

I've got an old backup file: `mmcblk0.img`

I'm wondering if there is any specific tool that can work with this file, as no standard partition tool has been able to view it. I think there's a chance it might be encrypted actually, but due to this even though I do in fact have the password I don't know how to input it somewhere so it can be decrypted successfully because I couldn't find any tool that is specifically set up with the understanding of how Android filesystem structure is. Any ideas?