# How to mount full image backup properly?

Tags: file-system, linux, mount, android-10

Did a full backup `mmcblk0.img` of a Redmi Note 7 (codename `lavender`) running Android 10.

However, I'm not sure how exactly to mount it or view files. Worth noting that I was suffering from an encryption problem, but once I retrieved the correct password I'm still stuck on where exactly to insert it into the file. It might not be encrypted at all to begin with, but I can't access it with regular Windows tools that I'm used to. There might be some Linux magic that can tinker with it, but I'm not the best so I'd appreciate any basic guidance on that part. I've heard that the Linux `kpartx` tool can interact with it but as a Linux noob I don't consider myself an expert on this side of things, hence asking the question.

Comment: standard partition tool [parted](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219730) will work

Comment: What might be encrypted is the data partition, not the whole partition table. `parted` / `gdisk` must be able to see a valid partition table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dig deep into mmcblk0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250912/44325). Hi, it seems you accidentally created a duplicate account. Please refer to [the help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts and regain ownership of the question and reply to the comments on your post.

Comment: @AndrewT. Apologies for the duplicate. Please remove the original if you can.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I've merged the original question to preserve some useful comments from the original.

Comment: @alecxs Any tips on how exactly to deal with `parted` on this? (bit of a Linux noob here)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4568789

Comment: Windows was and most likely will never be able to mount a partition used on an Android phone. Use a Linux system.

Comment: even the latest WSL cannot mount f2fs